# Joining two select queries but one is grouped

Tags: mysql

I have a (entrance)ticket table with a **ticket_code**, a **timestamp_processed** and an **event** code.

i.e.:

```
ticket_code         event             timestamp_processed
---------------------------------------------------------
44185909829105549   TICKET_ACCEPTED   1434636748
```

Now I want to count the occurrence of every event = 'TICKET_ACCEPTED' until the end of a specified time frame.

I use this query:

```
SELECT ticket_code, COUNT(ticket_code) count 
FROM rest_history 
WHERE timestamp_processed <= :endTime AND event = 'TICKET_ACCEPTED' 
GROUP BY ticket_code
```

Now I want to get only the count and ticket_codes of a specific time range with a startTime.

Here is the query to get all ticket_codes in a specific time range:

```
SELECT ticket_code 
FROM rest_history 
WHERE timestamp_processed >= :startTime AND 
timestamp_processed <= :endTime AND 
event = 'TICKET_ACCEPTED'
```

Now I want to INNER JOIN both queries or build one using a subselect, but I can't get the right solution. Can someone give me a hint?

Update:

In the end I want a GROUP BY ticket_code with the individual count of each occurrence of every ticket_code with the event = 'TICKET_ACCEPTED' in the specific timeframe but the count value should include all occurrences until endFrame and not just since "startTime".

i.e:

```
[ticket_code] => 1434636748 [count] => 3
[ticket_code] => 3434636745 [count] => 1
[ticket_code] => 2434636546 [count] => 10
```

Comment: Can you add some more explanation on what you want to do? And why you're trying to do it this way (inner join)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would work:

```
select t1.ticket_code, t1.count from
(SELECT ticket_code, max(timestamp_processed) lasttime, COUNT(ticket_code) count 
FROM rest_history 
WHERE timestamp_processed <= :endTime AND event = 'TICKET_ACCEPTED' 
GROUP BY ticket_code) as t1
where t1.lasttime >= :startTime
```

by using max(timestamp), we are making sure that any ticket with a timestamp_processed >= starTime gets included with that greatest timestamp in the subquery, so that it then passes the test of the outer query.

Comment: Because I want to count every occurrence until "endTime". Then I want to limit the output to only those who where accepted in the specific time frame (startTime..endTime)

Comment: Ooohhh!  ok, that will require a subquery.  Give me a sec.

Comment: Thank you! It really works. Now I have to dig in and try to understand. I really like your optimization with max(timestamp_processed).

Comment: In case it helps - my thought process was something like this:  the first query was getting at the set of rows you needed to work with.  You then needed to select from those rows using the second query, testing on startTime.  The problem was that to test on that, the results of the first query had to have that timestamp in them, but to add the timestamp to a grouped query, some sort of aggregate/group function had to be used because the grouping could not include the timestamp.  So which group function would give us a summary timestamp that would be appropriate (min, max, avg...?).

Comment: Would appreciate an upvote if you think the answer is useful.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Unfortunately, I can't upvote, because I need "15 reputation".

Answer (score 1):

Possibly joining the table against itself. Untested but something like this:-

```
SELECT a.ticket_code, COUNT(b.ticket_code) 
FROM rest_history a
LEFT OUTER JOIN rest_history b
ON a.ticket_code = b.ticket_code
AND b.timestamp_processed <= :endTime 
AND b.event = 'TICKET_ACCEPTED'
WHERE a.event = 'TICKET_ACCEPTED'
AND a.timestamp_processed >= :startTime 
AND a.timestamp_processed <= :endTime 
GROUP BY a.ticket_code
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't give me my needed results. I had a similar idea, but wasn't able to get it right.